What is the probability that 4 random bytes all increase in value?
From a randomness test @ https://www.vmpcfunction.com/c6.htm (2/3rds down the page):-
Four-Byte-Run-Up Test
The sequence is divided into four-byte segments. If the first byte of the segment is less than the second, and the second byte is less than the third, and the third is less than the fourth, a four-byte-run-up is said to have occurred. In a random sequence the probability of a four-byte-run-up is 2,731,135 /67,108,864.
A ‘sequence’ is an infinite series of unsigned random bytes that range [0,255] inclusive.
Can someone please verify that the probability (approx. 0.0407) is correct?

Similar but simpler than Random Sequence of Alternating Increase/Decrease Numbers.

If the bytes were guaranteed to be different the probability is $\frac 1{4!}=\frac 1{24}$  Your value is quite close to this, so I assume it is correct and the difference comes because any time two bytes match you fail.

@RossMillikan Yes, that's the correct interpretation.  Bytes must be greater than to count; not equal.

The given probability value looks good to me.

A four-byte-run-up is uniquely specified by an unordered selection of four bytes, chosen from the set of all $256$ bytes. Therefore, the number of possible four-byte-run-up’s is $\binom{256}4$. To compute the probability, you take the number of four-byte-run-up sequences, and you divide by the total number of sequences of four bytes, which is just $256^4$. Therefore, the probability is $$\frac{\binom{256}4}{256^4}.$$ This is equal to $2\,731\,135/67\,108\,864$.
